# Purpose of CDI technology in Java EE and its relation to UI technologies like JSF and back end technologies like EJB

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

This question directly follows from another question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967978/understanding-datacontrol-abstraction-in-adf-framework). The last paragraph of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13977308/1527084) to that question mentions `CDI` technology.

Can you explain what is the purpose of that technology. Is there any relation of that technology with JSF and EJB? I have been through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047807/why-use-cdi-in-java-ee) but I'm not clear on what is the purpose of that technology yet. I specifically want to know where it fits with other Java EE technologies like EJB and JSF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding to the correct answer of Bozho:

CDI is a superset of JSF's managed beans, and JSF will eventually deprecate their own native managed bean system. In JSF 2.2 steps have already been taken for this.

CDI is not a superset of EJB beans, but they complement each other. CDI does not only provide more advanced DI to EJB beans, but is also capable of giving EJB beans a scope (mostly used for stateful beans). EJB on its turn provides transactional and security services among others , which CDI does not offer. Like JSF managed beans, EJB beans will eventually be merged into the CDI component model. Marina Vatkina (EJB spec lead) among others has [strongly hinted](https://blogs.oracle.com/marina/entry/ejb_3_2_news) at this.

Further reading:

- [How do CDI and EJB compare? interact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684112/how-do-cdi-and-ejb-compare-interact/4705840#4705840)
- [CDI, when to break out the EJBs](http://blog.dblevins.com/2012/11/cdi-when-to-break-out-ejbs.html)

Answer (score 3):

First, CDI is a dependency-injection standard framework. It defines ways for objects to obtain their dependencies not through instantiation (`private FooDao dao = new FooDao()`) but via a container which creates and manages instances. You can read more about dependency injection (google/wiki).

The standard defines how that works with both JSF and EJB.

- your JSF managed beans can be defined via CDI, so that you can inject services into the managed beans, and so that CDI manages the lifecycle of JSF managed beans
- EJB can also benefit from the advanced dependency injection of CDI (previously they had their own, feature-poor DI).

In short, CDI binds all components in JavaEE in a way spring does with all of its components, but CDI is a standard.